# How to set the yrange as variable and then use them in yrange and in set arrow

Tags: gnuplot

I am having trouble in assigning yrange variable and use then in the rest of the gnuplot script.

I assigned the yrange variable as Y11=-10 and Y22=10
and tried to use them in yrange as set yrange ["$Y11":"$Y22"]
and
set arrow from 0.0,"$Y11" to 0.0,"$Y22" nohead
set arrow from 0.67643,"$Y11" to 0.67643,"$Y2" nohead
but it is giving me error
 "plot.gnu line 66", Can't plot with an empty y range!

This is a simple variable efforts

```
Y11=-10
Y22=10
```

want to use in

```
set yrange ["$Y11":"$Y22"]
```

and

```
set arrow from 0.0,"$Y11" to 0.0,"$Y22" nohead
set arrow from 0.67643,"$Y11" to 0.67643,"$Y22" nohead
```

Could you please correct me so that I can store yrange variables and use then in the rest of the script as explained above?

Comment: You don't need quotes and dollar sign: `set yrange [Y11:Y22]`

Comment: Thanks Dear Michael. It helped me a lot.